# Modifying browser properties to fake fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible using Javascript to make website believe that it is in full screen mode. Like we can overwrite document.visibilityState and document.hidden properties of browser to make website believe that its tab is always active. So is there anything similar for Fulscreen

Comment: Yes, extensions can override these in [page context](/a/9517879).